# org-mode command to create new file from subtree?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, is there a command like `new-file-from-subtree`?

As I envision it, this command would cut the subtree from the current file, paste the subtree into a new buffer, then save the new buffer with the name of the subtree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe such a command currently exists.  However the following will do the trick:

```lisp
(require 'org-element)

(defun zin/org-file-from-subtree (&optional name)
  "Cut the subtree currently being edited and create a new file
from it.

If called with the universal argument, prompt for new filename,
otherwise use the subtree title."
  (interactive "P")
  (org-back-to-heading)
  (let ((filename (cond
                   (current-prefix-arg
                    (expand-file-name
                     (read-file-name "New file name: ")))
                   (t
                    (concat
                     (expand-file-name
                      (org-element-property :title
                                            (org-element-at-point))
                      default-directory)
                     ".org")))))
    (org-cut-subtree)
    (find-file-noselect filename)
    (with-temp-file filename
      (org-mode)
      (yank))))
```

As is, it will not promote the current heading to level 1, it will retain the existing depth.  (Promotion should be doable as well, but would require more complex code).  It also gives the option of prompting for a new filename, using `C-u`.

Comment: Awesome! Any way to make it append `.org` to the filename? What about making it return me to the original buffer I was working from?

Comment: Also I tried to add a keybinding but it didn't work. Clearly I'm doing something wrong. `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key "C-c C-x n" 'my-zin-org-new-file-from-subtree)))`

Comment: Added the ".org" appending to the filename when created from the headline title.  It will also now open the new file in background but not change buffers.

Comment: For the keybinding, change it to `"\C-c\C-xn"` and it should work.

Comment: Is `&optional name` used at all?!